# Dynamic flink window creation by reading the details from kafka

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Let's say Kafka messages contain flink window size configuration.

I want to read the message from Kafka and create a global window in flink.

**Problem Statement:**

Can we handle the above scenario by using BroadcastStream ?

Or

Any other approach which will support the above case ?

Comment: Are you trying to have the window change size while the job is running, or simply initialize the window from data provided via Kafka?

Comment: Based on the configuration message. It has to be initialize if it contain new information or if it is same information with new window size then it should change the window size without restart.

Answer (score 3):

Flink's window API does not support dynamically changing window sizes.

What you'll need to do is to implement your own windowing using a process function. In this case a KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction, where the window configuration is broadcast.

You can examine [the Flink training](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/training/event_driven.html#example) for an example of how to implement time windows with a KeyedProcessFunction (copied below):

```
public class PseudoWindow extends KeyedProcessFunction<String, KeyedDataPoint<Double>, KeyedDataPoint<Integer>> {
    // Keyed, managed state, with an entry for each window.
    // There is a separate MapState object for each sensor.
    private MapState<Long, Integer> countInWindow;

    boolean eventTimeProcessing;
    int durationMsec;

    /**
     * Create the KeyedProcessFunction.
     * @param eventTime whether or not to use event time processing
     * @param durationMsec window length
     */
    public PseudoWindow(boolean eventTime, int durationMsec) {
        this.eventTimeProcessing = eventTime;
        this.durationMsec = durationMsec;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {
        MapStateDescriptor<Long, Integer> countDesc =
                new MapStateDescriptor<>("countInWindow", Long.class, Integer.class);
        countInWindow = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(countDesc);
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(
            KeyedDataPoint<Double> dataPoint,
            Context ctx,
            Collector<KeyedDataPoint<Integer>> out) throws Exception {

        long endOfWindow = setTimer(dataPoint, ctx.timerService());

        Integer count = countInWindow.get(endOfWindow);
        if (count == null) {
            count = 0;
        }
        count += 1;
        countInWindow.put(endOfWindow, count);
    }

    public long setTimer(KeyedDataPoint<Double> dataPoint, TimerService timerService) {
        long time;

        if (eventTimeProcessing) {
            time = dataPoint.getTimeStampMs();
        } else {
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        long endOfWindow = (time - (time % durationMsec) + durationMsec - 1);

        if (eventTimeProcessing) {
            timerService.registerEventTimeTimer(endOfWindow);
        } else {
            timerService.registerProcessingTimeTimer(endOfWindow);
        }
        return endOfWindow;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext context, Collector<KeyedDataPoint<Integer>> out) throws Exception {
        // Get the timestamp for this timer and use it to look up the count for that window
        long ts = context.timestamp();
        KeyedDataPoint<Integer> result = new KeyedDataPoint<>(context.getCurrentKey(), ts, countInWindow.get(ts));
        out.collect(result);
        countInWindow.remove(timestamp);
    }
}
```