# How to configure Flink window time based on its key

Tags: apache-flink

Differnt types of items arrive into a source which I partition them to different window by its 'type'. Now, each `type's` window has to be configured with its own  emit timeout than having one `.byKey("type").window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1))).allowedLateness(Time.seconds(5))`.

As an Example: 
{ {"type-1", 5m}, {"type-2", 10m}, {"type-3", 1m} }

So, elements added to a keyed window of `type-1` has the emit time of 5 minutes, similarly the `type-2` with 10 minutes and so on.

I can do this by maintaining a state with list of times in `KeyedProcessFunction`, `registerProcessingTimeTimer` with the timeout configured for the key.

But, instead of having need to manage the state & elements, how do I do this using `window`? I tried with custom `Trigger` but couldn't clearly make it work.

Comment: The example I shared in this answer -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59823254/2000823 -- may help if you end up using a `KeyedProcessFunction`.

Comment: Are these per-key timings static (i.e., known at compile time)?

Comment: At the very least you would need a custom window assigner, but if the per-key timing information isn't static, and needs to be maintained in flink state, I'm not sure how to do that and make it available to the window assigner.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - Looking for something similar and in my case the per key timings are static. Could you please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post below the code-fix to my custom `Trigger` approach. I havent not used the `Evictor` as suggested by @David, but used the FIRE_AND_PURGE in `onProcessingTime`. This approach seems to work having tested in few scenarios.

Slot configuration

```
private static final Map<String, Long> eventSlots = new HashMap<>();

static {
    eventSlots.put("type22", 30000l);
    eventSlots.put("type12", 15000l);
    eventSlots.put("type9", 10000l);
    eventSlots.put("type2", 20000l);
    eventSlots.put("type7", 13000l);
}
```

processing code

```
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Event> sourceStream = ...

someSourceStream
.keyBy("type")
.window(GlobalWindows.create())
.trigger(new Trigger<Event, GlobalWindow>() {

 @Override
 public TriggerResult onElement(Event element, long timestamp, GlobalWindow window,
         TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
     ctx.registerProcessingTimeTimer(ctx.getCurrentProcessingTime() + eventSlots.get(element.getType()));
     return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
 }

 @Override
 public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long time, GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx)
         throws Exception {
     return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE;
 }

 @Override
 public TriggerResult onEventTime(long time, GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx)
         throws Exception {
     return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
 }

 @Override
 public void clear(GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
     ctx.deleteProcessingTimeTimer(window.maxTimestamp());
 }

}).process(new ProcessWindowFunction<Event, Events, Tuple, Context> () {
     @Override
     public void process(Tuple arg0,
         ProcessWindowFunction<Event, Events, Tuple, GlobalWindow>.Context ctx,
         Iterable<Event> arg2, Collector<Event> arg3) throws Exception {
       List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
       arg2.forEach(events::add);
       arg3.collect(new Events(events));
});
```

Comment: Yes, it could be that FIRE_AND_PURGE is enough, and you don't need a custom Evictor. I updated my answer.

Comment: If just have a handful of event type with static window sizes, you could also split your stream per event type and apply a normal window on each substream.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with GlobalWindows, along with a custom Trigger (and possibly a custom Evictor). An alternative might be to use a custom window assigner.

In general I discourage going deep into the custom window API, because the resulting solutions end up being hard to understand.