# What is the correct way of connecting a ProcessWindowFunction with a broadcast stream in Flink?

Tags: java, stream, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink pipeline with mutiple models running, so that the windowing looks like this:

```
DataStream<WindowDeviationResult> aggregatedWindow = keyedStream
                                                        .timeWindow(Time.seconds(window_duration))
                                                        .aggregate( model.getWindowAgreggator(), 
                                                                    model.getWindowProcessor());
```

I need to send state coming from another stream to the ProcessWindowFunction operator (the last one). Normally, I'd do a connect right before, and implement the *proceessElement* and *processBroadcastElement*. But because I'm passing the WindowProcessFuction to .aggregate as a second parameter I can't do that. What options do you see for me here?

Answer (score 0):

Flink does not support connecting a broadcast stream to a window operator. What I should suggest is to use a KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction rather than a window, and implement your own windowing. Typically this isn't especially difficult. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59823254/2000823 for an example that may help you get started.

Comment: His this is a very useful answer,. The only thing that concerns me is if it will be able to handle late arrivals?

Comment: Yes, no problem. You'll have to decide how long to keep each window's state before clearing it (i.e., the _allowed lateness_), and then as late events arrive, if their window no longer exists you can send the late event to a side output -- and if the window does exist, you can process the late event.

Comment: Excellent. I ended up doing a different solution, but your comment and solution will come in very handy for later problems!